# Mapbox AddressAutofill not filling postcode

Tags: reactjs, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I am trying to implement the AddressAutofill feature in a form of my react app, but having trouble get the post-code field to be filled out. Other fields get autofilled correctly, it's specific about the post-code.

I reproduced it in isolation, this is a simple example in a clean React app. the name of the attributes are taken from the example of this guide (https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-search-js/tutorials/add-address-autofill-with-react/#add-address-autofill) :

```js
import { AddressAutofill } from '@mapbox/search-js-react';

function App() {
  return (
    <form>
      {/* eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/ban-ts-comment */}
      {/* @ts-ignore next-line */}
      <AddressAutofill
        accessToken={import.meta.env.VITE_MAPBOX_TOKEN as string}
        options={{
          language: 'en',
          country: 'US',
        }}
      >
        <>
          <input name='address1' placeholder='Address Line 1' />
          <input
            name='postcode'
            placeholder='Postcode'
            type='text'
            autoComplete='postal-code'
          />
        </>
      </AddressAutofill>
      <input name='city' placeholder='City' autoComplete='address-level2' />
    </form>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I also checked in the network call to make sure that the suggestion that I select has a valid postal-code and it does.

Any suggestion on what I might be doing wrong?

Thanks!!